# Robot Framework: Parse the Output and Store in required format

Tags: robotframework, keyword

1. I get the list of Kubernetes Pods in the below format. Only the BOLD part of the string is fixed. This list can have more elements and list length is variable.

   xxyyy-**cas-0-0**
   xxyyy-**cas-1-0**
   xxyyy-**cas-2-0**
   xxyyy-**cas-0-1**
   xxyyy-**cas-1-1**
   xxyyy-**cas-2-1**
   xxyyy-**dbaccess-0-0**
   xxyyy-**dbaccess-1-0**
   xxyyy-**dbstorage-0-0**
   xxyyy-**dbstorage-1-0**
   **kf**-xx-yyy-**kafka-0**
   **kf**-xx-yyy-**kafka-1**
   **kf**-xx-yyy-**kafka-2**
   **zk**-xx-yyy-**kafka-0**
   **zk**-xx-yyy-**kafka-1**
   **zk**-xx-yyy-**kafka-2**
2. I want to parse this Output and store it in below format in a file. So BOLD string will be the variable name.

   ```
    ${cas-0-0}        xxyyy-cas-0-0
    ${cas-1-0}       xxyyy-cas-1-0
    ${cas-2-0}       xxyyy-cas-2-0
    ${cas-0-1}        xxyyy-cas-0-1
    ${cas-1-1}       xxyyy-cas-1-1
    ${cas-2-1}       xxyyy-cas-2-1
    ${dbaccess-0-0}       xxyyy-dbaccess-0-0
    ${dbaccess-1-0}       xxyyy-dbaccess-1-0
    ${dbstorage-0-0}       xxyyy-dbstorage-0-0
    ${dbstorage-1-0}       xxyyy-dbstorage-1-0
    ${kf-kafka-0}       kf-xx-yyy-kafka-0
    ${kf-kafka-1}       kf-xx-yyy-kafka-1
    ${kf-kafka-2}       kf-xx-yyy-kafka-2
    ${zk-kafka-0}       zk-xx-yyy-kafka-0
    ${zk-kafka-1}       zk-xx-yyy-kafka-1
    ${zk-kafka-2}       zk-xx-yyy-kafka-2
   ```
3. I wrote a keyword which stores the variable, value as it is.

   ```
    *** Settings ***
    Documentation     This file contains Pod Details

    *** Variables ***

    ${xxyyy-cas-0-0}       xxyyy-cas-0-0
    ${xxyyy-cas-1-0}       xxyyy-cas-1-0
    ${xxyyy-cas-2-0}       xxyyy-cas-2-0
    ${xxyyy-dbaccess-0-0}       xxyyy-dbaccess-0-0
    ${xxyyy-dbaccess-1-0}       xxyyy-dbaccess-1-0
    ${xxyyy-dbstorage-0-0}       xxyyy-dbstorage-0-0
    ${xxyyy-dbstorage-1-0}       xxyyy-dbstorage-1-0
    ${kf-xx-yyy-kafka-0}         kf-xx-yyy-kafka-0
    ${kf-xx-yyy-kafka-1}         kf-xx-yyy-kafka-1
    ${kf-xx-yyy-kafka-2}         kf-xx-yyy-kafka-2
    ${zk-xx-yyy-kafka-0}         zk-xx-yyy-kafka-0
    ${zk-xx-yyy-kafka-1}         zk-xx-yyy-kafka-1
    ${zk-xx-yyy-kafka-2}         zk-xx-yyy-kafka-2
   ```

Below is the Keyword. It's not the most efficient, suggestions are most welcome for improvement.

````
```     
    Create File   ${Hostfile}   *** Settings ***\n
    ${Doc1}=        catenate     Documentation       ${SPACE}        ${SPACE}        This file contains Pod Details
    Append To File    ${Hostfile}     ${Doc1}\n\n
    Append To File    ${Hostfile}    *** Variables ***\n\n   
 
    SSHLibrary.Write                kubectl get pods -n ${SDL_NAMESPACE} | awk {'print $1'} | column -t | sed '1d'
    ${outputP}        Wait Until Keyword succeeds    120s    2s    SSHLibrary.Read Until Prompt
    BuiltIn.Log     ${outputP}

    @{listP}=    Split to lines      ${outputP}
    FOR    ${line}   IN    @{listP}
         Log     ${line}
         ${tempP}=        catenate     SEPARATOR=   \$\{   ${line}   \}
         
         ${appendP}=     Catenate      ${tempP}     ${SPACE}    ${SPACE}    ${SPACE}     ${line}
         Append To File    ${Hostfile}      ${appendP}\n
    END
```
````

4. I found switch statement is not available in robot framework. IF-ELSE will be lengthy implementation if number of elements from the list in POINT #1 is more.

Please suggest me how to write an efficient keyword in Robot Framework to get the format as in POINT #2.
Thanks In Advance!

````
```
    [root@47fd8b28cb33 /]# robot --version
    Robot Framework 4.0.3 (Python 3.6.8 on linux)
```
````

Comment: Do you require that the keyword be written in the robot syntax? This looks like it would be way easier to write in python.

Comment: If all members are in one of 2 fixed formats as in the sample, you can go with regexp - if it matches the 1st format, replace (through regexp again) the unwanted part, if not - repeat with the 2nd.

Comment: BryanOakley: Yes, trying to maintain the entire code in Robot framework. 
Is it possible to design such a keyword although complex
can you please help with that ?

Comment: @TodorMinakov: Thanks for you response. 
Can you please share an example for its usage